# z-index of CSS carousel slide

Tags: html, css, carousel

Friends, i wanted to create my own pure CSS based carousel with radio buttons for navigation. It works fine but there is one problem that I am unable to solve and need your guidance please.
Whenever a radio is checked, its relevant slide animates to front with higher z-index. Problem is by default all the other slides have same z-index therefore the last slide is always visible at the back.
Is there a way to show the previously checked slide at the back without using any script?
Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/alikhan99/sg9qy5um/1/

```css
#slider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideWrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide2 {
  background-color: #090;
}

.slide3 {
  background-color: #009;
}

.slide4 {
  background-color: #900;
}

#slide1:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:first-child,
#slide2:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 2;
  animation: slideAnimation 4s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input checked type='radio' name='slider' id='slide1' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide2' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide3' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide4' />

  <div class="slideWrapper">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slideContent">
        <h2>Slide One</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slideContent">
        <h2>Slide Two</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slideWContent">
        <h2>Slide Three</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide4">
      <div class="slideWContent">
        <h2>Slide Four</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```css
#slider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideWrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: slideAnimation1 4s ease 0s forwards;
}

.slide2 {
  background-color: #090;
}

.slide3 {
  background-color: #009;
}

.slide4 {
  background-color: #900;
}

#slide1:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:first-child,
#slide2:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked~.slideWrapper .slide:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 2;
  animation: slideAnimation 4s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes slideAnimation1 {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input checked type='radio' name='slider' id='slide1' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide2' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide3' />
  <input type='radio' name='slider' id='slide4' />

  <div class="slideWrapper">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slideContent">
        <h2>Slide One</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slideContent">
        <h2>Slide Two</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slideWContent">
        <h2>Slide Three</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide4">
      <div class="slideWContent">
        <h2>Slide Four</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: friend u are collapsing rest of the slides